# Adding a Key-Value pair in a dictionary from another file.py

Tags: python-3.x

So I started to learn python a few weeks ago, and I am now stuck on a problem...
So I really need to add or edit a key-value pair of a dictionary from another file

For example, the fist file is named base.py:

```
plat_principaux = {
    "Boeuf haché (à point)" : [0, 20.69, 24.07, 289],
    "Crevettes" : [0, 1.08, 20.91, 99],
    "Poulet rôti (sans peau)" : [0,7.41, 28.93, 190]
}

accompagnement = {
    "Salade frisée" : [2.79, 0.15, 1.36, 15],
    "Salade de pommes de terre": [11.17, 8.2, 2.68, 143],
    "Courgettes cuites" : [2.68, 0.36, 1.14, 15],
    "Concombre cru" : [3.63, 0.11, 0.65, 16],
    "Semoule de maïs" : [76.89, 3.59, 8.12, 362]
}

dessert = {
    "Gateau au chocolat": [10, 20, 30, 200],
    "Flan à la vanille - 100g": [22.6, 3.78, 1.45, 130],
    "Mars": [71.17, 17.23, 4.01, 456],
    "Yaourt glacé - 100g": [24.2, 5.6, 4, 159],
    "Test pourcentage dessert": [30, 50, 30, 20]

}

boisson = {
    "Coca - 100g" : [9.56, 0.02, 0.07, 38],
    "Vin rouge - 100g" : [2.61, 0, 0.07, 85],
    "Test pourcentage boisson": [10,50,50,50]
}
```

So my question is:
from file1.py, how to I open base.py, and add or edit a key-value pair into the dictionary I want?

for now, I only know how to write something in base.py, but I have no clue how to add this information to one of the dictionary:

```
file = open(base.py, "w")

x=input("name")
y=input("detail1 ")
z=input("details2")
a=input("details3")
b=input("details4")

boisson[x] =[y, z, a, b]
```

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Show you work so that we can correct you.

Comment: Done, but this is as far as I can go...

Comment: In my opinion, you do not have to read values that way as long it is `*.py` file. Just use imports of these constants

Comment: @peter.cambal thanks! but I actually want to edit base.py file so 
boisson[x] =[y, z, a, b] is be part of it!..